# secure json data

Tags: json, post

I have an app that's gathering registration data (username/password, etc).  I need to gather the registration data as JSON and post it to my webservice for processing.  What's the best way to secure the data transmission?  What are some strategies for securing the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is sending the json request over https. If thats not an option you could encrypt the data using a 2 way algorithm directly in javascript before sending but remember that you cant hide javascript code so your "security" could be broken very easy and of course you will be reinventing the wheel

Comment: thanks for everyone's replies.  I did some more research and found a jQuery.sha256.js script that will hash a string (password).  I'm retrieving a salt value from my server to "saltify" the hash.  I'm returning the hash+salt password and salt value to the server to create the user record.  So, the password never is transmitted across the internet.  Is this a safe approach?

Comment: Sounds like a good solution for a small project or component but if you want good security you should go for ssl. That way not only you will know that the information is secured, your user will know it too.

Answer (score 0):

Best possible solution would be of course using SSL. There are some other precautions that you should consider whenever using JSON for data transfers.

For example, [what is described in this article](http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/2006/01/advanced-web-attack-techniques-using.html). Not quite securing the data itself but it prevents some of the hackery that could be done with it. Also make sure your JSON file cannot be accessed from foreign domains (done on the server side).

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I do not have a JSON file.  I'm handling data returned from a webservice and the data is stored in either memory, or browser's local storage.  I did some more research and found a jQuery.sha256.js script that will hash a string (password). I'm retrieving a salt value from my server to "saltify" the hash. I'm returning the hash+salt password and salt value to the server to create the user record. So, the password never is transmitted across the internet. Is this a safe approach?

Comment: That's what I actually meant with saying 'JSON file', they work in quite the same way when looking from the outside. This crypting is definitely better than nothing so why not? :)